# ManyToMany relationship and the join table in relation ManyToMany with another Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

after searching a lot with no luck I decided to ask my question here, so I will start by giving an example to make things clear.

I have 4 classes A - B - C - D
I have a ManyToMany relationship between A and B called A_B (I know how to code this using @idClass or @Embeddable and @embeddedId)

now what I need is to make a ManyToMany relationship between A_B and C so I will have another join table called A_B_C

the A_B_C class will be also in ManyToMany relationship with D and I'll get a A_B_C_D join table.

If anyone can help me solve this, I'll be grateful thanks.

Comment: A join table cannot have a "relationship" (assuming that is what you mean A_B represents). The only way you can do that is have an intermediate A_B entity, then 1-N between A and A_B, and N-1 between A_B and B, and then hang your relation off the A_B entity

Comment: yes I agree with you and this is just what I did I created a A_B entity, but my problem is how to create another manyToMany relation between A_B and C, I know I will create a A_B_C entity but what Next ?

Comment: Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I did the same process but the the A_B class have a composite key, so I don't know how to put it inside the A_B_C relation thanks for your time

Comment: so consult JPA docs, such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html

Comment: I didn't find a response for my problem in this link, did you understand where the problem is ? i think I should post some code

Comment: Why create a table just because you have a many to many associations? I mean, why to create A_B table because you have many to many relationship between A and B? instead you can do a `@ManyToMany` from A to B using a `@JoinTable` annotation

Comment: What do you mean what is next?  It sounded like you understood you have  an A with a 1:M to AB, which has a 1:M to ABC which in turn has either a M:M to D (using the A_B_C_D join table) or  another 1:M to an intermediary ABCD class.  If you are having problems with these mappings, show what you've done and the errors you get and we can point out what you are missing.

Comment: @Moshe Arad I created A_B table cause i have a manyTomany relationship between this table and another C table and the A_B_C table will also have another manytomany relationship with D table, so I have to create them

Comment: @Chris this is exactly what I want, and the answer you give is what I did before except that ABC has either a M:M to D with a 1:M to an intermediary ABCD class but I get the exception I mentioned in your response thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example using JPA composite pks might be:

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
  List<AB> abList;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="b")
  List<AB> abList;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ABId.class)
class AB {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  public A a;
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  public B b;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="ab")
  List<ABC> abcList;
}

class ABId {
  public Integer a;
  public Integer b;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ABCId.class)
class ABC {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  public AB ab;
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  public C c;
  @ManyToMany
  List<D> dList;
}

class ABCId {
  public ABId ab;
  public Integer c;
}
```

Comment: i've got this exception Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: com.test.entities.A_B_CId has no persistent id property

Comment: The example is incomplete. I don't understand that Hibernate error, but the id class should have a constructor and be serializable.  see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/IdClass

Comment: It worked I added a constructor, hashcode() and equals() functions thanks Chris do you know how to rename the join columns for the A_B_C table <code>@ Id
  @ ManyToOne
  public AB ab;<code>? will you update your code or should I update mine to select the answer ?

Comment: Ok I solved it I just added <pre>@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="B_ID")
    })<code> in the ABC class I will post my functional code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given by @Chris, this is my functional code.

**Class A :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long idA;
private Set<A_B> a_bs = new HashSet<A_B>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "A_ID")
public Long getIdA() {
    return idA;
}
public void setIdA(Long idA) {
    this.idA = idA;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<A_B> getA_bs() {
    return a_bs;
}
public void setA_bs(Set<A_B> a_bs) {
    this.a_bs = a_bs;
}

public void addA_B(A_B a_b){

    this.a_bs.add(a_b);
}

public A() {
    super();
}
}
```

**Class B :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class Matiere implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long idB;
private Set<A_B> a_bs = new HashSet<A_B>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "B_ID")
public Long getIdB() {
    return idB;
}

public void setIdB(Long idB) {
    this.idB= idB;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<A_B> getA_bs() {
    return a_bs;
}

public void setA_bs(Set<A_B> a_bs) {
    this.a_bs = a_bs;
}

public void addA_B(A_B a_b){

    this.a_bs.add(a_b);
}

public Matiere() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

**Class A_B :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A_B")
@IdClass(A_BId.class)
public class A_B implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private A a;
private B b;
private Set<A_B_C> a_b_cs = new HashSet<A_B_C>();

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
public A getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(A a) {
    this.a= a;
}

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
public B getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(B b) {
    this.b= b;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="a_b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<A_B_C> getA_b_cs() {
    return a_b_cs;
}
public void setA_b_cs(Set<A_B_C> A_b_cs) {
    this.a_b_cs = a_b_cs;
}
}
```

**class A_BId :**

```
public class A_BId implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long  a;
private Long b;
public Long getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(Long a) {
    this.a = a;
}
public Long getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(Long b) {
    this.b = b;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Code generated here
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Code generated here 
}
```

**Class C :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long idC;
private Set<A_B_C> a_b_cs = new HashSet<A_B_C>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "C_ID")
public Long getIdC() {
    return idC;
}

public void setIdC(Long idC) {
    this.idC= idC;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<A_B_C> getA_b_cs() {
    return a_b_cs;
}

public void setA_b_cs(Set<A_B_C> a_b_cs) {
    this.a_b_cs = a_b_cs;
}

public void addABC(A_B_C a_b_c){
    this.a_b_cs.add(a_b_c);
}

public Niveau() {
    super();
}
}
```

**Class A_B_C :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A_B_C")
@IdClass(A_B_CId.class)
public class A_B_C implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private A_B a_b;
private C c;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="B_ID")
})
public A_B getA_b() {
    return a_b;
}

public void setA_b(A_B a_b) {
    this.a_b = a_b;
}

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="C_ID", referencedColumnName="C_ID")
})
public C getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(C c) {
    this.c= c;
}
}
```

**Class A_B_CId :**

```
public class A_B_CId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private A_BId a_b;
private Long c;

public A_BId getA_b() {
    return a_b;
}
public void setA_b(A_BId a_b) {
    this.a_b = a_b;
}
public Long getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(Long c) {
    this.c= c;
}
public A_B_CId() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Code generated
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Code generated
}
```